# Is installing .crt certificate files in server and client enough for authentication?

Tags: ssl, client-certificates, x509certificate2

This is my first task with SSL and trying to implement SSL certificate authentication to a Web API. Company has provided four .crt files.

1. Internal_Root_CA.crt (All issuance policies, All application policies)
2. Internal_CA.crt (All application policies)
3. SSL_CA.crt (All application policies)
4. Dev.crt (Ensures the identity of a remote computer, Proves your identity to a remote computer)

   Certification path: Internal_Root_CA.crt => Internal_CA.crt => SSL_CA.crt => Dev.crt

I have gone through many tutorials but all used .pfx files. One of my colleague said as the .crt files don't have private key, password we just need to install these certificates in the server and client, no need to attach with the request. I am little confused because if it is like that, how the server differentiates the request is from proper client or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> One of my colleague said as the .crt files don't have private key, password we just need to install these certificates in the server and client, no need to attach with the request.

He is correct, except that the certificates will be sent before the request in a properly configured HTTPS exchange.

> I am little confused because if it is like that, how the server differentiates the request is from proper client or not?

What you've described is enough for *authentication,* but insufficient for *authorization.* It's nice to know that the person you're talking to is who he claims he is (authentication) , but whether that's the person you expected to be talking to, and whether he is *authorized* to access this part of the application, is something only the application can answer, by retrieving the peer certificate and checking the identity against some authentication/role database.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I think authorization is not required because this API will be accessed by only one client and they have full access. So just forcing the request to https is enough? If it is, anyone can send a request with https and access the API?

Comment: Not if the server requires client authentication and only trusts the one client certificate and nobody else has that client certificate. Not really the right way to do things.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. You mean enabling https is not enough?

Comment: No, the server has to require client authentication. As I said.